# How to drop index using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**Mongoose**

```
Imagdata.dropIndexes( { "image_id": 1 }, function(err){
         if(err){
             res.send("error");
        }
        else{
            res.send("success");
        }
});
```

This is the code I used for remove the index of a field 'image_id'. When I trying to execute this function It shows "TypeError: Imagdata.dropIndexes is not a function". How to fix this issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sync indexes. Check out this source : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes

```
const schema = new Schema({ name: { type: String, unique: true } });
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', schema);
await Customer.collection.createIndex({ age: 1 }); // Index is not in schema
// Will drop the 'age' index and create an index on `name`
await Customer.syncIndexes();
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the raw [`collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-collection) property of your model to access the underlying MongoDB API:

```
Imagdata.collection.dropIndex(...);
```