# Can I add index dynamically to my schema in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For example I have the following structure of documents:

```
{
    "subject":"Joe owns a dog", 
    "content":"Dogs are man's best friend", 
    "likes": 60, 
    "year":2015, 
    "language":"english"
}
```

And the schema would be:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    subject: {type: String},
    content: {type: String},
    likes: {type: int},
    year: {type: int},
    language: {type: String}
}

schema.createIndex({"subject": "text"});
```

Can I dynamically remove the index and create another one with more fields?

So if now it searches for a keyword in subject field, I would like to change it dynamically and search in "subject" and "content". to change to:

```
schema.createIndex({"subject": "text", "content": "text"});
```

Do you think that is possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can build dynamically indexes.

Using `ensureIndex(...);` mongoDB function.

To remove the index use `dropIndexes(...);` mongoDB function.

---

But I'm warning you, manipulating indexes is a major action, that's gonna have major impact on performances depending on the size of your collection.

By default mongoDB create indexes using foreground method, take a look at what mongoDB says about it:

> By default, creating an index blocks all other operations on a
>   database. When building an index on a collection, the database that
>   holds the collection is unavailable for read or write operations until
>   the index build completes

So if you want really create indexes dynamically, maybe you should consider to make mongoDB to create index in background:

> For potentially long running index building operations, consider the
>   background operation so that the MongoDB database remains available
>   during the index building operation.

[Here is full mongoDB documentation about Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#background-construction)

---

[ensureIndex(...) documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)

[dropIndexes(...) documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndexes/)

[getIndexes(...) documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/#db.collection.getIndexes)

[How to call directly mongoDB methods from mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450547/how-to-drop-index-using-mongoose)

Comment: Thanks. Then I will try to avoid changing index.